# comparator for min heap

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, priority-queue, min-heap

we know that in order to declare a minimum heap in c++ we can use the STL as follows:

```
priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>> minheap;
```

So please can someone explain to me why the `greater<int>`comparator need to be passed. I mean to ask that can someone explain to me the detailing of how the comparator is used in building this min-heap so that I can understand why specifically `greater<int>` is passed.

Comment: You can find documentation e.g. at cppreference.com, which would allow you to ask a more specific question. Basically, the behaviour follows the documentation, which answers your question, but is probably not at the core of what you're wondering about...

Comment: If `compare` is your comparison function, than `compare(a, b)` tells you whether `a` comes after `b`. By default the comparison function is `std::less`, so `a` comes after `b` if `a < b`, which means you get a max heap. If you use `std::greater`, then `a` comes after `b` if `a > b`, so you get a min heap.